# What is the correct way to pass and consume a byte array containing audio data?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, audio, aws-sdk

I've been trying to create a WepAPI C# REST service that will return a byte array containing  audio (generated by a TTS service, in this case AWS Polly).  I am lost as to how to consume the array in the javascript client.

My WebAPI service is as follows...

```
var client = new AmazonPollyClient("secret", "secret", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

var ssreq = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest();
ssreq.Text = "hello world";
ssreq.VoiceId = VoiceId.Nicole;

var ttsresp = new TTSResp();

//// mp3 request
ssreq.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Mp3;
var ssresp1 = client.SynthesizeSpeechAsync(ssreq).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var ms = new MemoryStream();
ssresp1.AudioStream.CopyTo(ms);
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
ttsresp.Audio = ms.ToArray();

return Ok(ttsresp);
```

The reason I am returning an object is that I want to attach other metadata.

My javascript client is as follows...

```
var context;    // Audio context
var buf;        // Audio buffer

window.onload = function () {
    context = new AudioContext();
}

function getSound() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/test',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success', data);

            var u8a = new Uint8Array(data.Audio.length);
            u8a.set(new Uint8Array(data.Audio), 0);   

            //error here - DOMException: Unable to decode audio data 
            context.decodeAudioData(u8a.buffer, play);
        },
        fail: function (err) {
            console.log('fail', err);
        }
    });
}

function play(audioBuffer) {
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
}
```

My audio bytes returned are as follows...

"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"

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: audio is not text, please remove that from your question as is doesn't help in anyway.

Comment: That looks like a base64-encoded byte array - have you tried base64 decoding it first?

Comment: I have not.  I admit I have no idea what that string is.  I certainly did not encode it so I am confused.

Comment: Put it in an online base64 decoder and see what comes out - looks like it's an mp3 file (when saved as a file).

Comment: What came out is an .mpga file, which is a playable audio file!

Comment: This also worked...
   `var snd = new Audio('data:audio/x-mp3;base64, '+data.Audio);
   snd.play();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that you received is base64-encoded. Before you can actually play it as audio, you need to base64-decode it into a byte array. (I did this and the data attached to the question is an mpga / mp3 file, after saving.)